# Adding rows to dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

How can I create a `DataSet` that is manually filled? ie. fill through the code or by user input. I want to know the required steps if I need to create a `DataTable` or a `DataRow` first, I really don't know the steps to fill the `DataSet`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id",typeof(int)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));

 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["id"] = 123;
 dr["name"] = "John";
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: Then after all these steps what should I do to add row to already existing datatable within dataset?

Answer (score 8):

```
DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();

DataTable customers = myDataset.Tables.Add("Customers");

customers.Columns.Add("Name");
customers.Columns.Add("Age");

customers.Rows.Add("Chris", "25");

//Get data
DataTable myCustomers = myDataset.Tables["Customers"];
DataRow currentRow = null;
for (int i = 0; i < myCustomers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    currentRow = myCustomers.Rows[i];
    listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} is {1} YEARS OLD", currentRow["Name"], currentRow["Age"]));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add rows to existing DataTable in Dataset:

```
DataRow drPartMtl = DSPartMtl.Tables[0].NewRow();
drPartMtl["Group"] = "Group";
drPartMtl["BOMPart"] = "BOMPart";
DSPartMtl.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drPartMtl);
```