# insert a column and data in to dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I went through many examples online and spent more time on it, but didn't work for me. i might be doing something wrong.

for existing dataset am trying to add columns by

```
 ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("columnName", typeof(string));
```

any suggestions how to add data to the added column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this way

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
      foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
      {
         string colName = col.ToString();
         if (colName.Contains("columnAmlooking"))
           row[columnAmlooking] = "inputvalue";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a moment:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("columnName",typeof(string)));
```

Found here: 
[adding-rows-to-dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125864/adding-rows-to-dataset)